# same css ,same html but different view from example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I will copy the  example of  bootstrap 
[offcanvas](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) ,but The page is smaller then example of  bootstrap on my server.The same css,same html who can tell me ,why

the example of bootstrap:
[image]
my page:
[image]

My page is smaller then bootstrap example.

the code of this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Off Canvas Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/static/autoapp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="/static/autoapp/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/static/autoapp/css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/static/autoapp/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
          </p>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
          </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
          </div>
        </div><!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
      </div><!--/row-->

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div><!--/.container-->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="/static/autoapp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="/static/autoapp/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/autoapp/js/offcanvas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your code or screen shot of what you are getting. Only give info like it is smaller than it is  expected to be wont give information to other to solve your problem. Please Edit your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem,the chrome can remember zoom,i set up long time ago

Answer (score 0):

You dont have all source files of example page. 
[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWJYZ.png) and compare with your code

Comment: Right click on page and inspect, check source files, I think you dont have some .css files , thats why its not same